# How to rigorously fill in certain steps in the proof of L'Hôpital's Rule as it appears in Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

**The following is L'Hôpital's Rule as it appears in Spivak's Calculus**

> Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a}
>  g(x)=0$
>
> and suppose also that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$
> exists.
>
> Then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, and
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim\limits_{x \to a}
>  \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

**Spivak then provides a proof of the theorem, and at the very end writes**

> (Once again, the reader is invited to supply the details of this part
> of the argument)

**The following is my attempt at supplying details of certain steps in the proof. There are two steps which I understand at an intuitive level, but not at a formal mathematical level.**

> The hypothesis that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists
> contains two implicit assumptions
>
> (1) there is an interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ such that $f'(x)$ and
> $g'(x)$ exist for all $x$ in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ except, perhaps,
> for $x=a$
>
> (2) in this interval $g'(x) \neq 0$ with, once again, the possible
> exception of $x=a$

To show this, recall that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$ means

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x,\ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \left | \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} -l \right |<\epsilon$$

Therefore, $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is defined in $(a-\delta) \cup (a+\delta)$, so $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ both exist and $g'(x) \neq 0$ in this interval.

Note that since this is a limit for $x$ approaching $a$ nothing is said about $f'$ and $g'$ at $a$.

> On the other hand, $f$ and $g$ are not even assumed to be defined at
> $a$

That is, all we assumed was $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a}
 g(x)=0$. This says something about values of $f$ and $g$ near $a$ but not at $a$.

> If we define $f(a)=g(a)=0$ (changing the previous values of $f(a)$ and
> $g(a)$, if necessary), then $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$. If
> $a<x<a+\delta$, then the Mean Value Theorem and the Cauchy Mean Value
> Theorem apply to $f$ and $g$ on the interval $[a,x]$ (and a similar
> statement holds for $a-\delta<x<a$.

**Why is the following step necessary**

> First applying the Mean Value Theorem to $g$, we see that $g(x) \neq
> > 0$, for if $g(x)=0$ there would be some $x_1$ in $(a,x)$ with
> $g'(x_1)=0$, contradicting $(2)$.

**Didn't we already know this fact, precisely from $(2)$?**

Now applying the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and $g$, we see that there is a number $\alpha_x$ in $(a,x)$ such that

$$[f(x)-0]g'(\alpha_x)=[g(x)-0]f'(\alpha_x)$$

or

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}$$

> Now $\alpha_x$ approaches $a$ as $x$ approaches $a$, because
> $\alpha_x$ is in $(a,x)$.

I understand this as: since $|\alpha_x-a|<|x-a|$ so $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies 0<|\alpha_x-a|<\delta$

> Since we are assuming that $\lim\limits_{y \to a} \frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)}$
> exists, it follows that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to a}
>  \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=\lim\limits_{y \to a}
>  \frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)}$$

**I don't quite understand how to prove this last step.**

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=l$ means

$$\forall \epsilon\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<|x-a|<\delta  \implies \left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |<\epsilon$$

**Where is the implication from $0<|\alpha_x-a|<\delta$ to $\left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |$?**

Answer (score 2):

**Didn't we already know this fact, precisely from (2)?**

---

$(2)$ is about $g'(x)$ being non zero in a punctured interval whereas MVT application concludes that $g(x)$ is also non zero in that interval.

---

**Where is the implication from $0<|\alpha_x-a|<\delta$ to $\left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |$?**

---

You agree that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=l$ means the following: $$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<|x-a|<\delta  \implies \left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |<\epsilon\tag 1$$

Since $0<|\alpha_x-a|<|x-a|, (1)$ also gives the following:$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<\color{blue}{|\alpha_x-a|}<|x-a|<\delta  \implies \left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |<\epsilon,$$
which can be re-written as:

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<\color{blue}{|\alpha_x-a|}<\delta  \implies \left | \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}-l \right |<\epsilon$$

which is same as saying: $\lim_{\alpha_x\to a} \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=l.$ Now just substitute $\alpha_x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

The implication comes from the definition of a limit. For each neighborhood of $l$, there is a neighborhood of $a$ where $\frac{f'}{g'}$ maps all elements of that neighborhood to elements in the neighborhood of $l$. It has been previously stated that $a_x\in (a,x)$, hence if $x$ belongs to an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $a$, then so does $a_x$. Also in the last step, we don't have the implication from $a_x$. The implication is due to the fact that $|x-a|<\delta$, while $|a_x-a|<\delta$ is both a consequence and a useful fact, that allows us to show that $\frac{f'(a_x)}{g'(a_x)}$ gets close to $l$.